# How to get title of content from the db by it's id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get title of category from db but I have id of this category. Categories and content have different tables but content are connected by field category with categories table. How can I load title of the category but not id????

The code that creates content are follows:

```
 <form action="create_content.php" method="POST" id="content_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="content_text">
           <p><label for="title">Title:</label></p>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="">
        </div>                  
        <div class="content_textarea">
            <p><label for="text">Text</label></p>
                <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="20" form="content_form">    
                </textarea></div>
        <p><label for="text">Add image</label></p>
        <div class='add_image'><input type="file" name="content_pic"></div>                 
        <select name="category">
            <?php foreach ($result as $item) {?>
                <option value="<?php print $item['id'] ?>"><?php print $item['cat_title'] ?>                                
                </option> <?php }?>
        </select>                                       
        <div class="submit_content">
            <input type="submit" value="Send"></div>
 </form>


create_content($_POST['title'], $_POST['text'], $_FILES['content_pic'], $_POST['category']);



function create_content($title, $text, $content_pic, $category) {

      $title = trim($title);
      $text = trim($text);
      $category= $category;

      if (!empty($content_pic)) {
        if ($content_pic ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
          $uploads_dir = __DIR__ . '/files';
              $tmp_name = $content_pic ["tmp_name"];
              $name = $content_pic ["name"];
              if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "{$uploads_dir}/{$name}")) {
                $content_pic = "files/{$name}";
              }
        }
      } 

      $db = database_connect();
      /*if ($id) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE INTO content (id, title,text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt -> execute(array($title ,$text, $id ));
      }
      else {*/

      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO content (`title`,
              `text`,`content_pic`, `category`, `author`, `time`) 
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
      $stmt -> execute(array($title, $text, $content_pic, $category, $_SESSION['user_id'], time()));  

      header("Location: review.php?id=" . $insertId=$db->lastInsertId());
      exit();

    }
```

Code that renders view:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $select_query = "SELECT `c`.`title`,`c`.`content_pic`,`c`.`text`,
                            `c`.`status`,`c`.`category`, `u`.`login`, 
                            `u`.`id` AS `user_id`, `c`.`time`
                       FROM content c
                  LEFT JOIN users u ON c.author= u.id 
                      WHERE c.id = ?";

      $db = database_connect();
      $stmt = $db->prepare($select_query);
      $stmt->execute(array($id));
      $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if ($result) {
        $row = $result;
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content_pic =  $row['content_pic'];
        $text =  $row['text'];
        $category= $row['category'];
        $created = !empty($row['time']) ? date('d.m.Y H:i', $row['time']) : '';
        $author = 'Anonymous';
        if (!empty($row['login'])) {
          $author = '<a href="review_account.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] .
                    '">' . $row['login'] . '</a>';
          }
      }

    ?>
<?php if ($result) {?>
        <div id="destinations_content">
            <div id="item_view">
                <div class="items">
                    <div class="items_title">                   
                        <?php print $title ?>                   
                    <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my_pic">
                        <img src="<?php print $content_pic ?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                <?php print $text ?><br>

              <?php print $created?>
                </div>
             <?php print $category ?>
            </div>
        </div>   
<?php }?>
```

Comment: can't you just echo your $row['title']  or in this case $title what do you get?

Comment: I can't echo it because I have only id of category but not title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you join category table as well to get category title. Since you have mapped content table with category table.(I assumed your category table name is "category"). How do you get that $row['cat_title'], i don't see any cat_title in the select query ?

```
$select_query = "SELECT `c`.`title`,`c`.`content_pic`,`c`.`text`,`c`.`status`,`c`.`category`, `u`.`login`, `u`.`id` AS `user_id`, `c`.`time`, cat.title as cat_title
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN users u ON c.author= u.id
INNER JOIN categories cat ON c.category= cat.id  
WHERE c.id =."(int)$id;
```

Comment: table called categories. This line $row['cat_title'] by mistake here.

Comment: what do yo uget when you run the query?

Comment: did you change "category" table to "categories"?  echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); die; let me see then? and you want category  title or item title?

Comment: if I put your code it doesn't display anything even with print_r and yes I changesd it to categories

Comment: echo $select_query;  run the result in phpmyadmin. see what happens?

Comment: if I add this cat.title as cat_title it gives me follows SELECT `c`.`title`,`c`.`content_pic`,`c`.`text`,`c`.`status`,`c`.`category`, `u`.`login`, `u`.`id` AS `user_id`, `c`.`time`, `cat`.`title` as `cat_title` FROM content c LEFT JOIN users u ON c.author= u.id INNER JOIN categories cat ON c.category= cat.id WHERE c.id =?

Comment: problem was because here cat.title was wrong name, it should be cat.cat_title as row in table categories called cat_title